# PHP arrays work differently for objects vs values

Tags: php, arrays

Here's my code:

```
$words = array();
$word = "this";
$words[] = $word;
$word = "that";
$words[] = $word;
print_r($words);

class word{
    private $text;
    public function __construct($word){
        $this->text=$word;
    }

    public function setWord($word){
        $this->text=$word;
    }
}

$class_words = array();
$word = new word("this");
$class_words[] = $word;
$word->setWord("that");
$class_words[] = $word;
print_r($class_words);
exit;
```

Here's the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] => that
)
Array
(
    [0] => word Object
        (
            [text:word:private] => that
        )

    [1] => word Object
        (
            [text:word:private] => that
        )

)
```

I expected the second output to match the first in that the array should store 'this' and 'that'.  It seems `array_name[] = <item>` makes a copy to the item when it's an array of values but not so when it's an array of objects.  How do I make it copy the object to the array instead copying a reference to the object?  Do I need to create a new object each time I need to add an object to the array?

Comment: That's because that's how String Arrays and Objects work.  They are difficult to mxi

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the value of the object into the array you need to write a "getter" for the value e.g.

```
class word{
    private $text;
    public function __construct($word){
        $this->text=$word;
    }

    public function setWord($word){
        $this->text=$word;
    }

    public function getWord() {
        return $this->text;
    }
}

$class_words = array();
$word = new word("this");
$class_words[] = $word->getWord();
$word->setWord("that");
$class_words[] = $word->getWord();
print_r($class_words);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] => that
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hGBiL)

Answer (score 1):

`$x = new X();` stores a reference to an object into `$x`. A subsequent `$y = $x;` *copies the reference, not the object*, so `$x` and `$y` both refer to the same object.

PHP has rather complex semantics regarding references.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are always references; all your uses of $word refer to the same object and the same data structure. You need to do:

```
$class_words=[new word('this'),new word('that')];
```

Answer (score 0):

Both elements of your array hold the same object.  So whenever you make a change in that object, all references to that object will show that change-- they're all referring to the *same object* in its *current state*.

As mentioned previously, if you want different values, you need to either instantiate new objects, or get the property value via a `getter()` that returns a simple value (string, integer, boolean, etc), not the object itself.

As a side note, you can leverage the referential nature of objects to chain methods (`$Obj->method1()->method2()->method3()`) by having a method return a reference to the object, i.e., `return $this;`